# Add unity quicklist launcher with a zenity command

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, zenity

I try to add a quicklist launcher for gedit that allowed me to open a new doc in gedit directly from unity dash

so I tried to add this command to my OpenDoc Shortcut Group

```
[OpenDoc Shortcut Group]
Name=Open file...
Exec=gedit $(zenity --file-selection)
TargetEnvironment=unity
```

But nothing happens when I click on the quicklist launcher...

Maybe someone know who to do it ?

Best Regards

Comment: For now, I find a solution, but it's not a beautiful one. 

I create a file with the command :

    'gedit $(zenity --file-selection)'

I save it under 

    '~/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit/geditzenity'

and I allow the file been executed.

Then I modify gedit.desktop with this quicklist shortcut :

    '[OpenDoc Shortcut Group]
    Name=Open file...
    Exec=~/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit/geditzenity
    TargetEnvironment=unity'

and it works. But little bit babarian don't you think ?
Maybe someone have a better idea.

BR,

Comment: You should post that as an answer, so that we can vote on it and it doesn't get buried in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so finaly I find a great solution for this case.

As I said before in a comments, the better solution is to use a script called with the Ayatana shortcut. This is an exemple of Quicklist launcher for gedit. With it you can open a file in gedit or open a file as root in gedit

The part I add in the gedit.desktop file :

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=OpenDoc;OpenDocRoot;

[OpenDoc Shortcut Group]
Name=Open file...
Exec=/path/to/the/script normal-mode
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[OpenDocRoot Shortcut Group]
Name=Open file as root...
Exec=/path/to/the/script root-mode
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Using a script fine is more easier for testing what we want and do some complex things with the quicklist shortcut.

Now this is the code for the script /path/to/the/script (personally I create a script folder in ~/.local/applications/ folder and create the script geditshortcut in it)

```
#!/bash/bin

case $1 in
normal-mode) gedit $(zenity --title='Open file...' --file-selection);;
root-mode) gksudo -u root -m "Running Gedit as user root allow you to modify some essential files of your system" "bash -c 'gedit \$(zenity --title=\'Open file as user root...\' --file-selection)'";;
esac
```

Now Drag & Drop the gedit.desktop file to the launcher bar or Unity and enjoy it ;)

That's all folks !!

Comment: Don't forget double quotes around the command substitution, `"$(zenity ...)"`, otherwise it won't work with filenames containing whitespace among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your solution in the comments, you could write a more generic script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1 $($2)
```

It would call the first argument with the output of the other, so you could Exec=`path/to/my/script gedit "zenity --file-selection"` Still a workaround, but easier to reuse in other cases.

Comment: Thx @Egil,

In fact, I thank about that this morning. With args option for the script (with a case command in it), I can easly set up lots of quicklist in launcher as, for exemple :

`#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
normal-mode) gedit $(zenity --file-selection)
su-mode) gksu gedit $(zenity --file-selection)
esac`

and then in launcher I think I can use : 

`[OpenDoc Shortcut Group]
Name=Open file... Exec=~/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit/geditzenity normal-mode
TargetEnvironment=unity`

==>

Comment: `[OpenDoc Shortcut Group]
Name=Open file... Exec=~/.local/share/applications/scripts/gedit/geditzenity su-mode TargetEnvironment=unity`

I'll try it and let you know

BR,

Comment: Ok, I test my little workaround and it seems to work fine. That's so great and more easly as I expected :). I'll finish the script and post-it as an Answer to this question. Thx